# How do I learn what I can do with /proc and /sys

Tags: linux, kernel, proc, sysfs

I'd like to know more about the advanced uses of the `/proc` and `/sys` virtual filesystems, but I don't know where to begin. Can anyone suggest any good sources to learn from? Also, since I think sys has regular additions, what's the best way to keep my knowledge current when a new kernel is released.

Comment: For the latter, I recommend the kernel mailing list. Failing that, the patch notes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Read this blog post: [Solving problems with proc](http://blogs.oracle.com/ksplice/entry/solving_problems_with_proc)

There are a few tips what you can do with the proc filesystem. Among other things, there is a tip how to get back a deleted disk image or how to staying ahead of the OOM killer.

Don't forget to read the comments, there are good tips, too.

Comment: Nice article. BTW, we prefer a small summary/explanation of whatever you link to, beyond just the title. That is, we need to know beforehand what you are asking us to visit.

Comment: I would vote up twice if I could

Answer (score 11):

You can look into the documentation which comes with the kernel source. (possibly greping for proc/sys ...).

Located at `Documentation/filesystems`: [proc.txt](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.37/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt) and [sysfs.txt](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.37/Documentation/filesystems/sysfs.txt).

Answer (score 3):

The documentation in the Linux source tree is a good place (usually found in /usr/src/linux/Documentation is source is installed). Some distros make a separate package out of it. But, alas, much of it can only be understood by looking at the kernel source code. I have tried to encapsulate some of it in [Python modules](http://code.google.com/p/pycopia/source/browse/trunk/core/pycopia/OS/Linux/), so you might also be interested in that. The [procps](http://procps.sourceforge.net/) source code is also a good source of information.

Answer (score 2):

The IBM DeveloperWorks library is a good place for articles like this. I didn't find anything directly applicable, but the 'Resources' section of a paper led me to this.  It has some good info...

http://www.comptechdoc.org/os/linux/howlinuxworks/linux_hlproc.html