# Where are the Linux kernel parameters present in /proc/sys documented?

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, documentation, parameter

Where can I find a technical description of the kernel parameters listed in `/proc/sys` (ob Linux)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Contents of /proc](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2732/contents-of-proc)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I learn what I can do with /proc and /sys](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6845/how-do-i-learn-what-i-can-do-with-proc-and-sys)

Comment: @Mikel These are not duplicates, they explain `/proc` and `/sys` but not `/proc/sys` (which is confusingly close in name but rather different in use).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The directory `/proc/sys` gives easy access to [sysctl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysctl) settings through the shell. You can read and write these settings either by reading and writing these files, or by calling the [`sysctl` utility](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sysctl) or the underlying [`sysctl` system call](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sysctl.2.html).

The various settings are described in the kernel documentation, in [`Documentation/sysctl/*`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/). Start with [`README`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/README).

This is fairly low-level stuff, so sometimes the documentation isn't completely precise and you'll need to turn to the source. Each sysctl setting usually corresponds to a variable with a resembling name inside the kernel (but this is a convention, not a rule). Many settings are declared in [`kernel/sysctl.c`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.39/kernel/sysctl.c), but additional kernel components and modules can define their own. In the source (on a local copy or online at [LXR](http://lxr.linux.no/linux)), search for the name of the sysctl setting between quotes (e.g. `"xfrm_larval_drop"`) to find its declaration.

Answer (score 8):

The authoritative source of what is in `/proc` is documented in the kernel source tree in [Documentation/filesystem/proc.txt](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=blob;f=Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt;h=f48178024067fd48fc3454806bdaa366c64dd966;hb=HEAD). That references [Documentation/sysctl](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=tree;f=Documentation/sysctl;h=e01f87d4c79870438e342e6ab419605e8f54b4c4;hb=HEAD) as the document that describes `/proc/sys`. That document references others in the kernel source tree documentation, so be prepared to navigate through that tree.

Those links are to a gitweb interface, so you can pick a particular version of Linux that you are interested in. Those links point to current HEAD.